# name 'pd' is not defined

Tags: python, pandas

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
print(dataset)
```

Error:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-bd7168d85704>", line 1, in <module>
    dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')

NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
```

Comment: just curious - did you pip install pandas?

Comment: @MarkQuinn he wouldn't get that error if he didn't. Bilal: from the traceback, we can see the error is thrown on line 1. Whereever you did the imports, it's not the same script as you're running.

Comment: You are using JupyterNotebook and didn't execute the first cell.

Comment: pandas has been installed in conda list and I am using spyder

Comment: Are you using the same environment?

Comment: I am using spyder in anaconda

Comment: Make sure that you run the cell with import pandas as pd first before you are running the code which requires the pandas. As you stated that you have installed pandas in conda environment, then make sure that you also need to launch spyder after activativation of that environment.

Answer (score 2):

From your comments, you're using Spyder. The traceback confirms to me that you're running `dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')` in the IPython interactive console.

Spyder has configurable namespace sharing between scripts and the console. Running:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
```

in a script makes all 3 modules accessible both to code within the script and within the interactive console. You could also run `import pandas as pd` in the console and then use `pd` there indefinitely. This import *may* or *may not* then be available in your scripts depending on what settings you have used.

Your issue is that you either:

1. haven't run `import pandas as pd` *anywhere*
2. You've restarted the kernel at some point and lost your imports
3. You've configured Spyder to wipe the namespace of your scripts each time they run, and haven't accounted for this.

Regardless of what settings you have with namespace sharing, *always* import modules into your scripts, don't rely on unusual quirks of Spyder because your code won't work elsewhere. What you do in the console is inconsequential.